# XAMPP new VH replaces localhost?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I am trying to create a new virtual host for one of my domains. I use XAMPP as my local test environment, and in the htdocs folder i have a folder with me website.

So i have this structure:
htdocs/mysite

I wanna be able to create a virtual host for mysite. So i have done the following:

**httpd-hosts in apache**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mySite"
     ServerName mySite.test
     ServerAlias *.mySite.test
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mySite"
     ServerName mySite.test
     ServerAlias *.mySite.test
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/mySite.test/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/mySite.test/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

I also installed an SSL certificate, but that is not my issue.

Then i changed the:

**host file**

```
127.0.0.1 mySite.test
```

So i restart everything, and this happens:

i try to go to **mySite.test** => Does NOT work, cannot find it.
If i go to **mySite.test.localhost** => it works.

Maybe this is working as intended? However, the weird issue is then that i cannot access my "regular" localhost anymore. If i try to go to localhost/dashboard to get the default dashboard, it goes to mySite again?

So it is like what i have done have completely "replaced" the localhost somehow? Yet, i always have to include it in my url adress, i cannot just say mySite.test?

I am pretty new to do virtual hosts, so please let me know what i am missing here.
thanks all

Comment: Undo the change you made in the httpd.conf

Comment: Virtual Hosts are in addition to locahost or any other VH's, you can have 100's of VH's

Comment: Not totally familiar with XAMPP and what they may have changed but the ssl config should go into `apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf` You will see lots of boilerplate some of which needs removing, but you will also see other parameters in there that need checking and possibly reading up on and setting to your desired settings

Comment: You can also create a VH for locahost, normally that is the first one in the list of VH's

Comment: @RiggsFolly i don't believe i made any changes to that file?

Comment: You said: ___`Then i changed the: host file 127.0.0.1 mySite.test`___

Comment: i feel like this is a lot of work of simply getting a local environment set. I am used to Visual Studio where you simply press "play" and it handles all this server-related stuff for you. Does something like this exist for PHP projects?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ah, that file is the one located here: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: Oh right, my mistake. Did you ADD `127.0.0.1 mySite.test` or replace `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: I ADDED the new one -- localhost is still there. But if i now just go to localhost my browser jumps to localhost/mySite - i cannot access the default localhost dashboard anymore - it changs EVERYTHING to my new site - and i still cannot just go mySite.test

Comment: Add  a Virtual Host for localhost `<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251428/discussion-between-j-b-j-and-riggsfolly).